# “The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.0) is ignored…”

Tags: android

In Android Studio 3.0.2, I'm seeing this issue:

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018

The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

Here is a screenshot of my project:

[image]

Comment: What is your question? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Answer (score 4):

If the question is - "How to fix this error?" - then just change on this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
}
```

Be sure that you installed also through SDK manager in SDK Tools right version 27.0.3 (it will be showe after you will check in corner "Show Package Details")

However, probably you will have then more error in dependencies. When you will point the cursor of your mouse on the line with error, you should see tooltip with advice, how to repair this error - usually you just need to rewrite this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i appreciate your help .

Comment: But the build fails with this errors sorry to annoy you   .     startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users\NCreativeStudio\Desktop\androidfinal\app\build.gradle': 39: unexpected token: } @ line 39, column 1.
   }
   ^

1 error

Comment: Here is my build gradle :   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: I can totaly understand, I was fighting with gradle also on the beginning (actually I am still on beginning) :D Anyway I need to see you whole file, so please post here whole code from build.gradle (Module: ***). I think that you have some error in dependencies but I am not sure and I need to see it first. Here you can find my example of gradle file: https://github.com/PitrsxD/MiwokApp/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: Thank you here is my build gradle https://stackoverflow.com/a/49743467/7415441

Answer (score 1):

Thank you

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 27
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.mobilegts.appname"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true


    }

    dexOptions {
        // Prevent OutOfMemory with MultiDex during the build phase
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }


    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []// <-- disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGZbJ.jpg)

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).